# Column from ClientTemplate undefined

Tags: javascript, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a KendoGrid column `List` that is a list of strings and a JS function that iterates through it and uses a simple template. What happens is that if I click the button on my toolbar, the error: `List` is undefined appears. But the column has nothing to do with the button, they aren't connected in any way.

Kendo Column + Button

```
//..rest of the grid
columns.Bound(od => od.List).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#=generateTemplate(List)#");
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add"))
....
```

My Js function

```
  function generateTemplate(List) {
     var template = "<ul>";
     for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
     template = template + "<li>" + List[i] + "</li>";
      }
     return template + "</ul>";
   }
```

My model

```
   [Display(Name ="List")]
    public List<string> List { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a simple one of `initialisation` of the list property.

When you click your add button the grid is setting up your new model based on the definition you have given it. So if you haven't defined the property then it will be null by default (from memory) if it isn't a `standard` property e.g. string, number, datetime etc.

so when you click add it tries to apply the template to the list property and if you haven't given this a default value. eg. new List then the value will be null and as you are not putting a check into your javascript function to test for if the list is `null` or `undefined` it will blow up an error.

So I would suggest applying a check for a null valued list within your js so something like:

```
function generateTemplate(List) {
  var template = "<ul>";
  if (list === null || list === undefined) {
    template = template + "<li>N/A</li>";
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
      template = template + "<li>" + List[i] + "</li>";
    }
  }
  return template + "</ul>";
}
```

as a side note although you have said the button and the column are not connected they are due to the MVVM framework the grid is using when it initialises a model and binds it to the current row.

Any issues let me know and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I solved it adding your version and a default value . Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped. I have fallen foul of this one a number of times in the past.